# How do you convert file date and time stamp (date modified) to minutes in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, cmd

I'm trying to convert date and time stamp found on a file (date modified ) to minutes, e.g. 29/08/2014 12:18 to X amount of minutes.

```
 name    date modified        type         size 

 blah    29/08/2014 12:18     txt          1kb
```

Comment: what do you mean by x amount of minutes? What is your expected answer in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample batch file demonstrating how to calculate something within a batch file.

```
@echo off
set Hour=12
set Minute=18
set /a "Minutes=Hour*60+Minute"
echo Number for minutes for %Hour%:%Minute% is %Minutes%.
```

For details about command `set` with option `/A` enter in a command prompt window either `help set` or `set /?` or read documention of command [set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490998.aspx).